# Can't make a simple MySQL REPEAT work

Tags: mysql

Please tell me what's wrong with this. It exactly follows the syntax in the 5.5 manual:

```
SET @RunID = 55;
REPEAT 
SET @RunID = @RunID + 1;
UNTIL @RunID = 100 
END REPEAT;
```

It keeps telling me I have a syntax error in the REPEAT. 
My wild guess is that it could have something to do with the fact that MySQL is running on Mac OS X and the client I'm using is Windows XP. End-of-line characters?

Comment: Is it a part of Stored Procedure? If not try to create Stored Procedure like this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/886cad/1 and test it...

Comment: Currently it is not part of a stored procedure. Does it have to be? The MySQL manual neglects to mention this.

Comment: I ran it in sqlfiddle as you suggested and it works. But not in other places.

Comment: I'm not quiet sure does it have to be in SP, but for me it works in stored procedure and I get error when i try it to execute it out of stored procedure... Why you wouldn't create stored procedure and use it that way :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem with `UNTIL`. I guess you want to run the Loop UNTIL RunID has reached 100, not just when RunID IS 100...

Try this:

```
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE dorepeat2(p1 INT)
BEGIN
  SET @RunID = p1;
  REPEAT
      SET @RunID = @RunID + 1;
    SELECT @RunID;
  UNTIL @RunID <= 100 END REPEAT;
END
//
CALL dorepeat2(55)//
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears it was a bit more complicated than I thought. This works:

```
USE pim;           # trying to run it complained no database was in use
SET @RunID = 55;   # can't define a user variable inside a procedure(?)
DELIMITER //       # so the procedure code can be parsed as 1 statement
CREATE PROCEDURE dorepeat()
BEGIN
    REPEAT 
      SET @RunID = @RunID + 1;
      UNTIL @RunID = 100 
    END REPEAT;
END 
//
DELIMITER ;        # restore the standard MySQL delimiter

CALL dorepeat();   # call the procedure
SELECT @RunID;     # returns 100
```